# Redirect error in php with isset and GET variable

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to make some redirects to lock the page from having a different get variable from what i have defined. But the problem is that I am getting a redirect error which is
The page isn’t redirecting properly.

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I tried different things but I could not solve this problem. I need your help please. It is to note that the variables w_news and the rest are coming from links on the page.

these are the following code which are in the header of the project:

```
  // Redirect function
  function redirect_to($redirect_link) {
    header("Location: ". $redirect_link);
    exit;
  }

  $redirect_link = "index.php?sec=w_news";
  //if sec is empty i want to redirect to the above link
  if (!isset($_GET['sec']) || isset($_GET['sec']) && $_GET['sec'] == "") {
    redirect_to($redirect_link);
  } else if (isset($_GET['sec']) && $_GET['sec'] != "w_news" || $_GET['sec'] != "pol" || $_GET['sec'] != "sci" || $_GET['sec'] != "tech" || $_GET['sec'] != "spo" || $_GET['sec'] != "covid19"){
    // and if the value is not = to the named ones i want also to redirect
    redirect_to($redirect_link);
  }
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The failed part is redirecting to same part as the passed part?

Comment: @CliveAtkins sorry just noticed i got a reply, what i am trying to do is lock the link, which means if the user enters index.php, i want it to be redirected to the above link, and if user enters an empty $_GET variable "sec" also i want to redirect, and finally if the user enters a variable not equal to "w_news" or "pol" or "tech" or "sci" or "spo" or "covid19" i also want to redirect them to that link

Comment: @CliveAtkins if i remove the else if , then the first if works well, so problem is with else if but i don't know so far how to do it right :/

Comment: added a solution check it and let me know

Comment: @CliveAtkins if i redirect_to("page_not_found.php") it redirects me to it but none stop, like if I enter manually "index.php?sec=w_news" it redirects me also to page_not_found.php

Comment: are you running this on a page called index.php? That will cause a loop?

Comment: I am running it on a page called header.php which is included in index.php. About your solution, I have made it redirect_to("page_not_found.php") in the else {} so it is always redirecting me to that page_not_found.php :/

Comment: There is your problem copy the code to a file called 1.php and run it by going to your website.com/1.php it will redirect as the get is missing. Then close browser and visit again this time type website.com/1.php?sec=pol. Then third test website.com/1.php?sec=123 and it will fail and pass to default. Even though you included the file it will still load index.php first hence the loop.

Comment: @CliveAtkins If i understand you well, you need to copy the code from your solution in a separate file called 1.php, so i did it still redirects me to index.php?sec=w_news with failed error above

Comment: ive added a simple solution which you can add to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

if ($_GET['sec'] == "w_news" || $_GET['sec'] == "pol" || $_GET['sec'] == "sci" || $_GET['sec'] == "tech" || $_GET['sec'] == "spo" || $_GET['sec'] == "covid19")
    {
    // working  validate
    }
else
    {
    //failed redirect"; 
    $redirect_link = "index.php?sec=w_news";
    header("Location: ". $redirect_link);
    }   

?>
```

Comment: did not work :/ it seems like there is an infinite loop or something, i have tried everything even the else{} before but still doesnt work :/ I even tried to redirect to a page_not_found.php so it always redirect to that page

Comment: I can't get what changed from the original code but you are a genius ! it worked ! so i added the if(!isset($_GET['sec'])) {redirect_to()} to the code and now the link is locked ! but i can not seem to understand the difference :/ I mean i see clearly that you have reversed my code and kept the first check empty

Comment: You don't need to add isset the code i gave you checks for the GET and the strings mentioned. If they are present you're good if not it redirects. That way no  more than one redirect ever. The old code was checking for no get then adding a get and checking again and going round in circles which would crash the browser.

Comment: yes you are right but when i typed "index.php" it through bunch of errors saying that sec is an undefined variable so i had to add the !isset, and hey Clive thank you so much for helping ! I really appreciate your help and solution :)

Comment: Add this at the start of your code $_GET['sec']= isset($_GET['sec']) ? $_GET['sec'] : ''; the error will go away